# Single entry to datatable triggers deadlock

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, deadlock

We have a webapi, which handles a lot of requests, sometimes per second and at the start of every request we send a log entry to our logtable using Entity framework.

However, often this entry to our logtable will deadlock on another process and I don't understand what is causing it.

```
using (UnitOfWork unitofwork = new UnitOfWork())
{
    unitofwork.WebApiRequestLogRepository.Insert(new WebApiRequestLog
    {
        Created = DateTime.Now,
        Username = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name,
        Controller = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName,
        Method = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName,
        MethodParameters = xml,
        ApplicationVersion = AppSettings.Instance.Version,
        Url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString(),
    });
    unitofwork.Save();
}
```

The unitofwork is a wrapper around a single context where multiple changes can be done at the same time. The save calls a context.SaveChanges

SQL Code that is generated by entity framework

```
INSERT [log].[WebApiRequestLog]([Created], [Username], [Controller], [Method], [ApplicationVersion], [Url], [MethodParameters])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6)
SELECT [Id]
FROM [log].[WebApiRequestLog]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()
```

Can anyone explain to me why a single insert into a log table can cause a deadlock?

**Edit**

```
public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
{
    DbSet.Add(entity);
}

public void Save()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            _context.Database.Log = s => builder.AppendLine(s);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            HandleDbEntityValidationException(e);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Exception ex = new Exception(builder.ToString(), e);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: We probably need the implementation of `UnitOfWork` and `WebApiRequestLogRepository`.`Insert` to know what is causing it. Any lock/transaction in there?

Comment: Take a look at for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/analyze-deadlocks-with-sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-2017 to get more information about what is actually locked. That can lead you to finding out why it's locked.

Comment: Are you using read committed snapshot isolation? If not you can easily get deadlocks from that because every select will will also add locks.

Comment: @Wanton: I have no idea, I assume this is a database setting? Where can I see what kind of isolation my database is using?

Comment: Default is Read Committed or Read Committed Snapshot is enabled that will be default and you can't use Read Committed isolatuon anymore without using WITH hint. Word of warning when Read Committed Snapshot is enabled some queries with inserts and updates might have race conditions they had before. `SELECT is_read_committed_snapshot_on
FROM sys.databases
WHERE [name] = 'MyDB'` 1 means enabled. More info about two snapshot isolations https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server

Comment: It's not enabled.

Comment: Well then every select will take a lock and risk of deadlocking is quite high if you don't lock all tables always in same order. It's very hard to do if you have lot of queries. If you have read committed snapshot on then normal selects won't lock at all because they read from snapshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am throwing a few helpful queries that you can run during a deadlock to show current waits. They may help you identify situations for a deadlock.

Also, you may want to lookup how to [save deadlock graphs](http://www.practicalsqldba.com/2012/07/sql-server-instant-deadlock-alert-using.html) to the database when they occur. If you posted a deadlock graph over at [Database Administrator Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com), I am sure you would find out more information about what is locking.

1. Make sure you are not breaking in a TransactionScope or that **another developer is sitting on a breakpoint** inside a `TransactionScope` block of code.
2. If your database is super busy and you are not worried about dirty then you can reduce read locks with the hints below.

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE SaveWebApiRequestLog(...)
   AS BEGIN
       SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED 
       INSERT log.WebApiRequestLog(Created,Username,Controller,Method,ApplicationVersion,Url,MethodParameters)
       VALUES(...)
       SELECT Id FROM log.WebApiRequestLog
       WHERE Id = @@IDENTITY
   END
   ```

   OR

   ```
   INSERT [log].[WebApiRequestLog]([Created], [Username], [Controller], [Method], [ApplicationVersion], [Url], [MethodParameters])
   VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6)
   SELECT [Id]
   FROM [log].[WebApiRequestLog] WITH NOLOCK
   WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()
   ```

Show Waits

```
--kill 65
SELECT 
    S.Text, R.Session_id,R.Status,R.Command,R.CPU_Time,R.Total_Elapsed_Time
FROM    
    sys.dm_exec_requests R
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS S 

--EXEC sp_who2
SELECT  W.session_id,ot.task_state,W.wait_type, W.wait_duration_ms, W.blocking_session_id, W.resource_description, S.host_name, S.program_name
FROM  
    sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks  W  
    INNER  JOIN sys.dm_os_tasks ot ON ot.task_address = W.waiting_task_address 
    INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions S ON S.session_id = W.session_id 
WHERE 
    S.is_user_process =  1

SELECT 
    SessionID = es.session_id,
    Login =es.original_login_name,
    Host = es.host_name,
    RequestStart=es.last_request_start_time,
    RequerstEnd=es.last_request_end_time,
    Status =es.status,
    BockedBy =er.blocking_session_id,
    WaitType =er.wait_type, 
    WaitTime = er.wait_time,
    LastWaitType = er.last_wait_type,
    WaitResource = er.wait_resource,
    DatabaseID = DB_NAME(er.database_id),
    Command = er.command,
    --,sql_text=st.text
    TransactionIsolation =
        CASE es.transaction_isolation_level
            WHEN 0 THEN 'Unspecified'
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Read Uncommitted'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Read Committed'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Repeatable'
            WHEN 4 THEN 'Serializable'
            WHEN 5 THEN 'Snapshot'
        END,
    CPUTime = COALESCE(es.cpu_time,0) + COALESCE(er.cpu_time,0),
    IOTime = COALESCE(es.reads,0) + COALESCE(es.writes,0) + COALESCE(er.reads,0) + COALESCE(er.writes,0),
    TransactioCount = COALESCE(er.open_transaction_count,-1),
    ProgramName = COALESCE(es.program_name,''),
    LoginTme = es.login_time
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_sessions es
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections ec ON es.session_id = ec.session_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests er ON es.session_id = er.session_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.server_principals sp ON es.security_id = sp.sid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_os_tasks ota ON es.session_id = ota.session_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_os_threads oth ON ota.worker_address = oth.worker_address
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(er.sql_handle) AS st
WHERE 
    es.is_user_process = 1 
    and 
    es.session_id <> @@spid
ORDER BY
     es.session_id
```